# UITableView how to change color?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, colors, tableview

How would I change the color of a UITableView? Or change the color of a cell? Or change the color of the navigation bar at the top? (iOS)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the color of a cell in the UITableView delegate method like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView 
               dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];

    if (!cell) {        
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
                                      reuseIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"]autorelease];
    }
}
```

//Here you can change de color/background of your cell with anything you want

//Change the color:

```
    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

//Change the background image of a cell:

```
    UIImage *theImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ximage.png"];
    [[cell imageView] setImage:theImage];
```

}

Comment: Thanks, but how would I change the navigation bar's color? I didn't add it in Interface Builder; it was created programatically.

Comment: UINavigationController* myNavController;

myNavController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];

Comment: exactly what I was looking for. I just put it in my app delegate.m, and it worked perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To change the color of a cell you need to create your own subclass of UITableViewCell. And to change the background color of the nav bar, I believe it is

```
self.navigationItem.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Thanks,

macintosh264

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by setting the backgroundView to the table and the contentView's backgroundColor of a cell. See [this](http://pessoal.org/blog/2009/02/25/customizing-the-background-border-colors-of-a-uitableview/) to get started with. The navigation bar can be done by subclassing the UINavigationBar and overriding the drawRect method.

P.S: All of the above are basic topics on which tutorials are littered all over the web and Stack Overflow itself. Try searching and reading up.

Answer (score 0):

note that as of ios3 you don't set the cell background color in

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
       cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

you set it in

- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

as noted here

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html